# antlr4 token recognition error at: '$'

Tags: antlr4

Trying to build a grammar for PowerScript language. I split the language in several parts and everything seems to be working except for the simple headers. It seems that the $ simbol can't be recognized. Could anyone help me a little? ( I just copy the small example I'm trying)

```
grammar PowerScript;

compilationUnit :   Header EOF;

fragment 
Header  : ID '.' ID;

ID : [a-zA-Z0-9$_]+ ;
```

test file just contains:

```
$PBExportHeader$n_logversion.sru
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `compilationUnit` rule is a parser rule. Parser rules cannot refer to lexer fragments. Just remove the `fragment` qualifier to make `Header` a proper lexer rule.

**Update**

Antlr4 is fully Unicode capable. Just include the characters in standard Unicode encoding form:

```
ID : ( [a-zA-Z0-9$_] | '\uD83D\uDCB2' )+ ; // Unicode heavy Dollar sign
```

Comment: Hi! First thanks.. but no.. It should be something related to linux or UTF. This is what i get from antlrv4 after changes:                                           line 1:0 token recognition error at: '$'
line 1:15 token recognition error at: '$'
line 1:1 mismatched input 'PBExportHeader' expecting Header
syntaxError
line 1:17 token recognition error at: '_'
line 1:28 token recognition error at: '.'

Comment: What changes? If the one suggested, then the problem lies elsewhere in the grammar. Post an actual working grammar the reproduces the problem.  If you are not actually using a `$` (U+0024) , then include the actual character in the list of characters in the `ID` rule.

Comment: Yes, It seems that the problem came from Java while I use UnitTest. I've tried today to compile and test the grammar in the terminal and it works fine.. Thanks and I sign the answer as correct.